# r ggplot legend exponent control

Tags: r, ggplot2

The legend in my plot occasionally shows values for the size variable as 1e+05. My audience is unlikely to know right away that this is the same as 100000, so I would like the legend to say 100000, 80000, 60000, 40000, 20000.  Is there anyway to control this exponent functionality in ggplot?

I have included the sample code with some fake data and an example image. You would have to re-run the code multiple times to get it to reproduce the problem shown.

[image]

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(DATE = c("2014-03-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-05-01", 
                      "2014-06-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-08-01", 
                      "2014-09-01", "2014-10-01", "2014-11-01", 
                      "2014-12-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-02-01"
                      , "2015-03-01"),
             TOTAL_VOLUME = rnorm(n = 13, mean = 53000, sd = 25000),
             NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME = rnorm(n = 13, mean = 8400, sd = 6000))

# Switch any negatives to positive
dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME <- abs(dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME)
# Could have NON_CONFORMING > TOTAL, set arbitrarily to 30% of total
dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME <- ifelse(dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME > dt$TOTAL_VOLUME, 
                               dt$TOTAL_VOLUME * .3, dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME)
dt$PERCENT_NON_CONFORMING <- dt$NON_CONFORMING_VOLUME / dt$TOTAL_VOLUME * 100

    p1 <- ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = DATE,
                        y = PERCENT_NON_CONFORMING, 
                        size = TOTAL_VOLUME)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  ggtitle("Percent Non-Conforming by Month") +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "% Non-Conforming") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(dt$PERCENT_NON_CONFORMING),
         colour = "darkorange")
plot(p1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised, when running your code I don't get scientific notation, I get 20000, 40000 etc. as you ask for. That said, the fix is to specify the `labels` function within the size scale, and the `scales` package has nice options. Probably the comma format will be best with this data, then you'll get 20,000, 40,000...

```
library(scales)
plot(p1 + scale_size_continuous(labels = comma))
```